# use cntk trained model with python

Tags: python, cntk

I have trained a model using CNTK, lets call simple.dnn
now for the phase of testing I do not want to install CNTK on windows,but use trained model with python. How can I use trained model (weights,...) for testing using python?

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `load_model` function, see https://www.cntk.ai/pythondocs/cntk.html?highlight=load_model#cntk.persist.load_model. The basic flow should look like this:

```
from cntk import load_model

loaded_model = load_model("yourModel.model", 'float')
output = model.eval(arguments)
```

Comment: can you give a longer example showing how to resume training from an existing model?